# How to get index in frozenset python

Tags: python-2.7

How to get index of certain value in frozenset?

```
 A= frozenset(['sungai','gunung'])
```

I want to get index of `'sungai'`?

Comment: A frozenset is an "immutable unordered collection of unique elements." The elements of a set are not indexed.

Comment: thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just have known, frozenset didn't have index. But i need it in my code.
I create a naive function:

```
def cariIndex(setList, data2):
   i=-1
   for data in setList:
       i=i+1
       if data==data2:
           return i
   return -1 

>> cariIndex(A, 'sungai')
   0
```